# What's the best way to switch columns and rows in a 2d array in Rust?

Tags: rust

If I have for instance a `Vec<Vec<i32>>` and I want to get the first column, what's the best way to do it? I have a feeling there's an elegant map solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean [`transpose`](https://docs.rs/transpose/0.2.0/transpose/)?

Comment: I don't think there's an expressive function to create a `Vec<i32>`, the issue being that the outer vec type doesn't necessarily need to contain an inner vec. You could of course write a helper function, or depending on your needs, iterating the first column might be sufficient `myVec[i][0]`?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood your question. Do you mean something like

```
let a = vec![vec![1,2,3], vec![4,5,6], vec![7,8,9]];
let b = a.iter().map(|x| x[0]);
for x in b { print!("{} ", x); }
```

Result: `1 4 7`

On [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab07020d8bb3f6877719ad20ea788e88)

Answer (score -1):

C14L's answer was almost what I was looking for. Here's what I eventually figured out:

```
let x : Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![0; 4]; 4];
let t : Vec<Vec<i32>> = (0..x[0].len()).map(|i| x
  .iter()
  .map(|c| c[i])
  .collect()
).collect()
```

or something along those lines, my actual use case was slightly different and I haven't tested this code.